# How do I forward parameters to other command in bash script?

Tags: bash, command-line

Inside my bash script, I would like to parse zero, one or two parameters (the script can recognize them), then forward the remaining parameters to a command invoked in the script. How can I do that?

Answer (score 351, accepted):

Use the [`shift`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-shift) built-in command to "eat" the arguments. Then call the child process and pass it the [`"$@"`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-_0040) argument to include all remaining arguments. Notice the quotes, they should be kept, since they cause the expansion of the argument list to be properly quoted.

Comment: actually "$@" is safer than $*

Comment: @pixelbeat: Thanks, good catch. I edited. @Łukasz Lew: see the linked-to page in the manual. :) Basically, it handles quoting better.

Comment: `$@` essentially treats each element of the array as a quoted string - they are passed along without opportunity for expansion. It also ensures that each is seen as a separate word. This explanation along with a test script demonstrating the difference is here: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html#APPREF

Comment: Pay attention to use quotes!
Read more on why it is important them around here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4824637/4575793

Comment: Note: If you are just trying to send all of the parameters to the function, don't use shift.

Comment: to clarify a quesiton I had before trying this solution: `"$@"` does not pass the script/command name itself as a parameter, unlike `sys.argv[0]` in C-family language. In other words, you're good to simply call whatever command it was as `cmd_inside_script "$@"`

Comment: @JaredBeach yes, I came to the same conclusion, I think the answer could benefit from a short explanation of why you would want to use `shift`, as even after reading the doc, I do not really understand the purpose of that command - but maybe I'm just dumb :)

Comment: Too many pending edits to add myself, but this answer would be improved with a simple code snippet example. It's unclear if `shift` requires arguments without looking at the docs or reading other answers with examples.

Answer (score 64):

Bash supports subsetting parameters (see [Subsets and substrings](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-bash-parameters/index.html#N10171)), so you can choose which parameters to process/pass like this.

1. open new file and edit it: vim `r.sh`:

   ```
   echo "params only 2    : ${@:2:1}"
   echo "params 2 and 3   : ${@:2:2}"
   echo "params all from 2: ${@:2:99}"
   echo "params all from 2: ${@:2}"
   ```
2. run it:

   ```
   $ chmod u+x r.sh
   $ ./r.sh 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
   ```
3. the result is:

   ```
   params only 2    : 2
   params 2 and 3   : 2 3
   params all from 2: 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
   params all from 2: 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
   ```

Answer (score 52):

bash uses the **shift** command:

e.g.
shifttest.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $1
shift
echo $1 $2
```

shifttest.sh 1 2 3 produces

```
1
2 3
```

Comment: @TamásZahola care to explain?

Comment: If you forward the arguments as `$1` without quoting them as `"$1"`, then the shell will perform word splitting, so e.g. `foo bar` will be forwarded as `foo` and `bar` separately.

Comment: Read more on why it is important to have the double " around here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4824637/4575793

Comment: My brain jumbled up a couple of letters in "shifttest" and I consequently read it as something else.

Comment: Doesn't this only answer half the question? How do you forward the remaining parameters? Rhetorical question: the accepted answer explains you use `forward-to-me.sh "$@"`