# In Unix / Bash, is "xargs -p" a good way to prompt for confirmation before running any command?

Tags: bash, unix, shell

I have asked how to make any command "ask for yes/no
before executing" in the question

[In Bash, how to add "Are you sure [Y/n]" to any command or alias?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3231804)

It seems like for the command

```
hg push ssh://username@www.example.com//somepath/morepath
```

I can also do this

```
echo ssh://username@www.example.com//somepath/morepath | xargs -p hg push
```

The `-p` is the one that does the trick. This will be set
as an alias, such as `hgpushrepo`. Is this a good way,
any pitfalls, or any better alternatives to do it? I was
hoping to use something that is standard Unix/Bash
instead of writing a script to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The disadvantage to using an alias is that it won't take parameters. If you wanted to generalize that `hg` command so you could use it with any username, hostname or path, you'd have to use a script or a function.

By the way, using a script *is* "standard Unix/Bash". A simple script or function is just as easy (easier, really, because of the increased power and versatility) as an alias. Aliases are useful for very short, extremely simple command shortcuts. Frequently they're used to enable an option as a default (eg. `alias ls='ls --color=auto'`).

For unchanging commands that you use frequently that don't need arguments (except those that can be appended at the end), aliases are perfectly fine. And there's nothing wrong with using `xargs` in the way that you show. It's a little bit overkill and it's an unnecessary call to an external executable, but that shouldn't be significant in this case.

Answer (score 1):

`xargs` has a nasty tendency to lead to uncomfortable surprises because of the separator problem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xargs#Separator_problem

GNU Parallel http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/ does not have that
problem and thus may be a safer choice.

```
seq 10 | parallel -p echo
```

Watch the intro video for GNU Parallel:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OpaiGYxkSuQ

Comment: Parallel doesn't have the prompt feature.

Comment: `seq 10 | parallel --interactive echo` seems to work just fine.

Comment: Excellent! Sorry, I don't know what I was looking at before. Thanks for pointing out the whitespace/quoting issue with `xargs`, too. Sorry, I can't upvote... but you could edit and quote `xargs`, allowing me to reverse my downvote...

Answer (score 0):

I use sometimes such wrappers to customize commands.

```
ls () { command ls -F "$@"; }
```

This defines a function wrapping the original command and keeps the `PATH` variable variable.