# Propagate all arguments in a Bash shell script

Tags: bash, command-line-arguments

I am writing a very simple script that calls another script, and I need to propagate the parameters from my current script to the script I am executing.

For instance, my script name is `foo.sh` and calls `bar.sh`.

foo.sh:

```
bar $1 $2 $3 $4
```

How can I do this without explicitly specifying each parameter?

Comment: Related: [How to pass all arguments passed to my bash script to a function of mine?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3811345/how-to-pass-all-arguments-passed-to-my-bash-script-to-a-function-of-mine)

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12314451/accessing-bash-command-line-args-vs

Comment: I had to use [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39463371/2172566) for my use case

Answer (score 1953, accepted):

Use `"$@"` instead of plain `$@` if you actually wish your parameters to be passed the same.

Observe:

```
$ cat no_quotes.sh
#!/bin/bash
echo_args.sh $@

$ cat quotes.sh
#!/bin/bash
echo_args.sh "$@"

$ cat echo_args.sh
#!/bin/bash
echo Received: $1
echo Received: $2
echo Received: $3
echo Received: $4

$ ./no_quotes.sh first second
Received: first
Received: second
Received:
Received:

$ ./no_quotes.sh "one quoted arg"
Received: one
Received: quoted
Received: arg
Received:

$ ./quotes.sh first second
Received: first
Received: second
Received:
Received:

$ ./quotes.sh "one quoted arg"
Received: one quoted arg
Received:
Received:
Received:
```

Comment: This does this work for pure pass through of quoted/escaped strings:

    Observe:
    cat rsync_foo.sh
    #!/bin/bash
    echo "$@"
    rsync "$@"

    ./rsync_foo.sh -n "bar me" bar2
    bar me bar2skipping directory bar me

    Is it possible to have shell script that can see the true original command line complete with quotes or escaped strings?

Comment: What about passing flags? Eg, './bar.sh --with-stuff'

Comment: I suggest anyone who wants to understand the subject of Word Splitting better, to [read more about it here.](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting)

Comment: I suggest you show what happens when including an `'arg with spaces'` for the three examples, too. I was surprised by the results; hopefully you can explain them.

Comment: @MichaelScheper, what's surprising? Quote parsing happens *before* parameter expansion, which happens *before* string splitting. Thus, literal quotes in the results of parameter expansions aren't honored as syntax. Whereas in the case of `"$@"` you're not performing string-splitting after expansion at all. Anyhow, we've already got Q&A entries explaining all of this in detail; [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) is a good related read.

Comment: @MichaelScheper, anyhow, `./foo.sh "arg with spaces"` and `./foo.sh 'arg with spaces'` are 100% identical, so I don't see how the suggestion of adding it to the examples given would be of any help.

Comment: Hmmm... I just tried it again, and it's indeed behaving as I would expect and as you say. I don't know what I was doing last time I tried; I thought I copied your code verbatim. Thanks for checking.

Comment: What if you pass option parameters, like `-e`, in my case, the `echo` cmd will consume it?

Comment: Shouldn't `baz.sh "$@"` be `./baz.sh "$@"` in the parent shell script?

Comment: It would have been to have explained what does these really do instead of having to guess from examples. https://stackoverflow.com/a/28099707/207661

Answer (score 519):

For *bash* and other Bourne-like shells:

```
bar "$@"
```

Comment: @Amir: No, not for *csh*. For everyone’s sanity: [do not script csh](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/shell/csh-whynot/). But I think maybe `$argv:q` will work in some csh variants.

Comment: Thanks! As desired, this passes the same set of arguments received by the script -- not one big argument. The double-quotes are necessary. Works even if with quoted arguments that include spaces.

Comment: Related: if your shell script is just acting as a wrapper to run java, consider making the last line `exec java com.myserver.Program "$@"` This causes bash to exec into java, rather than wait around for it to complete. So, you are using one less process slot. Also, if the parent process (which ran your script) is watching it via the pid, and expecting it to be the 'java' process, some unusual things could break if you don't do an exec; the exec causes java to inherit the same pid.

Comment: for some reason, I need to first do something like args="$@", first but then using $args would be treated as one single string? How to split it easily?

Comment: @dragonxlwang: You could use an array variable, if your shell supports them (e.g. *bash*, *zsh*, others, but not plain Bourne- or POSIX-shell): save to **args** with `args=("$@")` and expand each element as a separate shell “word” (akin to `"$@"`) with `"${args[@]}"`.

Comment: thanks @Chris, I am using zsh and it turns out by default it does not split string. To split it, expansion flag (${(s: :)args} is needed, or eval will do the trick

Comment: Are there any "gotchas" to keep in mind when using `"$@"`, like will it fail if you have escaped spaces in an argument, or null characters, or other special characters?

Comment: @IQAndreas Depends on what you are hoping to accomplish exactly. For the trivial use case "I want to pass on exactly what I received", `"$@"` works fabulously and doesn't require anything more.

Comment: I found java is off topic related to the question

Comment: Wait wait. How was this answer written before the question was asked? I need answers! <3

Answer (score 123):

Use `"$@"` (works for all [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_05_02) compatibles).

> [...] , bash features the "$@" variable, which expands to all command-line parameters separated by spaces.

From [Bash by example](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-bash2/#acceptargue).

Comment: So is "$@" not just quotes around $@ but in effect a different built in variable?

Comment: @ben It is a single variable but it requires the double quotes around it to have a useful value distinct from the (broken) `$*`.  I believe there is historical progression here; `$*` did not work as designed, so `$@` was invented to replace it; but the quoting rules being what they are, the double quotes around it are still required (or it will revert to the broken `$*` semantics).

Comment: "So is "$@" not just quotes around $@ but in effect a different built in variable?" -- For all intents and purposes, yes: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28099707/162094

Comment: If you call a script containing `echo "$@"` as `./script.sh a "b c" d` then you just get `a b c d` instead of `a "b c" d`, which is very much different.

Comment: @isarandi While it's true that the output no longer contains the quotes, that's what you would expect... but rest assured that within the script, `echo` receives three arguments: `"a" "b c" "d"` (then the shell joins them together as part of its string expansion). But if you'd used `for i in "$@"; do echo $i; done` You'd have gotten `a⏎b c⏎d`.

Comment: @tripleee is basically correct about that progression, `$@` was introduced to work around the problem that bare `$*` was dangerous since arguments could contain spaces, but `"$*"` was no solution because it ran them all together. (The previous solution was nonsense like `while [ "$#" -gt 0 ]; do MYARG="$1"; shift; something "$MYARG"; done` to replace what could be just `for MYARG in "$@"; do something "$MYARG"; done`.)

Comment: @isarandi You can use another expansion, `echo ${@@Q}` to get what you want.

Answer (score 117):

I realize this has been well answered but here's a comparison between "$@" $@ "$*" and $*

Contents of test script:

```
# cat ./test.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo "================================="

echo "Quoted DOLLAR-AT"
for ARG in "$@"; do
    echo $ARG
done

echo "================================="

echo "NOT Quoted DOLLAR-AT"
for ARG in $@; do
    echo $ARG
done

echo "================================="

echo "Quoted DOLLAR-STAR"
for ARG in "$*"; do
    echo $ARG
done

echo "================================="

echo "NOT Quoted DOLLAR-STAR"
for ARG in $*; do
    echo $ARG
done

echo "================================="
```

Now, run the test script with various arguments:

```
# ./test.sh  "arg with space one" "arg2" arg3
=================================
Quoted DOLLAR-AT
arg with space one
arg2
arg3
=================================
NOT Quoted DOLLAR-AT
arg
with
space
one
arg2
arg3
=================================
Quoted DOLLAR-STAR
arg with space one arg2 arg3
=================================
NOT Quoted DOLLAR-STAR
arg
with
space
one
arg2
arg3
=================================
```

Answer (score 107):

A lot answers here recommends `$@` or `$*` with and without quotes, however none seems to explain what these really do and why you should that way. So let me steal this excellent summary from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28099707/207661):

```
+--------+---------------------------+
| Syntax |      Effective result     |
+--------+---------------------------+
|   $*   |     $1 $2 $3 ... ${N}     |
+--------+---------------------------+
|   $@   |     $1 $2 $3 ... ${N}     |
+--------+---------------------------+
|  "$*"  |    "$1c$2c$3c...c${N}"    |
+--------+---------------------------+
|  "$@"  | "$1" "$2" "$3" ... "${N}" |
+--------+---------------------------+
```

Notice that quotes makes all the difference and without them both have identical behavior.

For my purpose, I needed to pass parameters from one script to another as-is and for that the best option is:

```
# file: parent.sh
# we have some params passed to parent.sh 
# which we will like to pass on to child.sh as-is

./child.sh $*
```

Notice no quotes and `$@` should work as well in above situation.

Comment: You can see this for yourself using `env --debug`. E.g. put `env --debug echo "$*"` inside a function and try executing it with different arguments.

Comment: Your example is wrong. `$*` passem them **not** as-is. Maybe it depends on how you define "as-is". Example: If you call `./parent.sh 'a b' c`, then in the parent script `$1` would eval to `a b` but in the child script `$1` would eval to only `a`. So this is not what I expect. I expect that both scripts "see" the same arguments and this only works with `./child.sh "$@"`.

Answer (score 41):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
while [ "$1" != "" ]; do
  echo "Received: ${1}" && shift;
done;
```

Just thought this may be a bit more useful when trying to test how args come into your script

Comment: this definitely did not help answer his question but this is indeed useful. upvoted!

Comment: It breaks when an empty parameter is passed. You should check for `$#`

Comment: good args tester, agree on `""`, `''` as an argument, also if there were no args it is silent. I tried to fix this, but needs a for loop and counter with `$#`. I just added this on the end: `echo "End of args or received quoted null"`

Comment: You can also simply do `env --debug <command> <args>` to get a similar output. Example: `env --debug echo "$@"`

Answer (score 9):

If you include `$@` in a quoted string with other characters the behavior is very odd when there are multiple arguments, only the first argument is included inside the quotes.

Example:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x
bash -c "true foo $@"
```

Yields:

```
$ bash test.sh bar baz
+ bash -c 'true foo bar' baz
```

But assigning to a different variable first:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x
args="$@"
bash -c "true foo $args"
```

Yields:

```
$ bash test.sh bar baz
+ args='bar baz'
+ bash -c 'true foo bar baz'
```

Comment: I won't deny that's disconcerting, but it actually makes sense within the semantics of `"$@"` in bash. It also helps illustrate the key difference between `$@` and `$*`, and why they're both useful. From the `bash(1)` man page Special Parameters section: "`*` — When the expansion occurs within double quotes, it expands to a single word with the value of each parameter […] That is, `"$*"` is equivalent to `"$1c$2c..."`, where `c` is [`$IFS`]." And indeed, using `$*` instead of `$@` in your first example would've netted output identical to the second version.

Comment: Now, compare that to `"$@"`. Again from the man page: "`@` — When the expansion occurs within double quotes, each parameter expands to a separate word. That is, `"$@"` is equivalent to `"$1"` `"$2"` … If the double-quoted expansion occurs within a word, the expansion of the first parameter is joined with the beginning part of the original word, and the expansion of the last parameter is joined with the last part of the original word." ...And indeed, if your code had been `bash -c "true foo $@ bar baz"`, then running it as `test.sh one two` would net `bash -c 'true foo one' 'two bar baz'`.

Comment: Thanks for the docs citation and info about `$*`, I seem to forget that it exists..

Comment: Heh. I'm the opposite, `$@` was just gaining traction when I first started shell scripting, I still have to remind myself it's there. It was common to see `"$*"` used in scripts... then the author would realize it was smashing all of their arguments together, so they'd try all manner of complex nonsense with word-splitting `"$*"`, or [re]assembling an arg list by looping over `shift` to pull them down one by one... just using `$@` solves it.  (Helps that bash uses the same mnemonic to access array members, too: `${var[*]}` for them all as a word, `${var[@]}` for a list of words.)

Comment: The real problem here is that you are using `bash -c` in a way which makes absolutely no sense.

Answer (score 6):

My SUN Unix has a lot of limitations, even "$@" was not interpreted as desired. My workaround is ${@}.  For example,

```
#!/bin/ksh
find ./ -type f | xargs grep "${@}"
```

By the way, I had to have this particular script because my Unix also does not support grep -r

Comment: This is a Bash question; you are using `ksh`

Answer (score 6):

Sometimes you want to pass all your arguments, but preceded by a flag (e.g. `--flag`)

```
$ bar --flag "$1" --flag "$2" --flag "$3"
```

You can do this in the following way:

```
$ bar $(printf -- ' --flag "%s"' "$@")
```

**note:** to avoid extra field splitting, you must quote `%s` and `$@`, and to avoid having a single string, you cannot quote the subshell of `printf`.

Comment: That doesn't work when arguments might contain `"` - you really need to use a `printf` that supports `%q` for this.

Answer (score 5):

`bar "$@"` will be equivalent to `bar "$1" "$2" "$3" "$4"`

Notice that the quotation marks are important!

`"$@"`, `$@`, `"$*"` or `$*` will each behave slightly different regarding escaping and concatenation as described in this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28099707/1534894).

One closely related use case is **passing all given arguments inside an argument** like this:

`bash -c "bar \"$1\" \"$2\" \"$3\" \"$4\""`.

I use a variation of @kvantour's answer to achieve this:

`bash -c "bar $(printf -- '"%s" ' "$@")"`

Answer (score 2):

Works fine, except if you have spaces or escaped characters. I don't find the way to capture arguments in this case and send to a ssh inside of script.

This could be useful but is so ugly

```
_command_opts=$( echo "$@" | awk -F\- 'BEGIN { OFS=" -" } { for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) { gsub(/^[a-z] /,"&@",$i) ; gsub(/ $/,"",$i );gsub (/$/,"@",$i) }; print $0 }' | tr '@' \' )
```

Answer (score 2):

`"${array[@]}"` is the right way for passing any array in bash. I want to provide a full cheat sheet: how to prepare arguments, bypass and process them.

`pre.sh` -> `foo.sh` -> `bar.sh`.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

args=("--a=b c" "--e=f g")
args+=("--q=w e" "--a=s \"'d'\"")

./foo.sh "${args[@]}"
```

```sh
#!/bin/bash

./bar.sh "$@"
```

```sh
#!/bin/bash

echo $1
echo $2
echo $3
echo $4
```

result:

```
--a=b c
--e=f g
--q=w e
--a=s "'d'"
```