# pass "$@" to AppleScript

Tags: macos, applescript, sh

So I have the following script saved as `usr/local/bin/spawn` which opens a process in a new terminal window, and then closes that window:

```
#!/bin/sh
osascript <<END
tell app "Terminal" to do script "$1; logout"
END
```

So I can do

```
$ spawn nano
```

to open a new terminal window with `nano` running, and when I close `nano` the window also closes.

However, to `spawn` a command with arguments, like `java -jar foo.jar`, I need to use

```
$ spawn "java -jar foo.jar"
```

Is there a way to change the script so that the same will work without the quotes? For example,

```
$ spawn java -jar foo.jar
```

I have tried using the trick from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3190826/667338) to a question that doesn't deal with AppleScript. However that always caused Terminal.app to crash when I tried using `spawn`. Is there a way to escape the `"$@"` or a different implementation for this problem? It doesn't necessarily have to use AppleScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/bin/sh
osascript <<END
tell app "Terminal" to do script "$@; logout"
END
```

seems to work for me.

Another option that would solve your problem would be to save the code to be executed in a file in a temporary folder and open it with Terminal like so:

```
#!/bin/sh
file=$(mktemp $TMPDIR/spawnXXXXXX)
echo '#!/bin/sh' > "$file"
echo "$@" >> "$file"
chmod +x "$file"
open -a Terminal "$file"
```

Or if you would like to open it in your current terminal program (Terminal, iTerm 2, etc.) you could use this script:

```
#!/bin/sh
file=$(mktemp $TMPDIR/spawnXXXXXX.command)
echo '#!/bin/sh' > "$file"
echo "$@" >> "$file"
chmod +x "$file"
open "$file"
```

Comment: That works, but doesn't solve the escape problem Lauri Ranta brought up.

Comment: @Fenhl I don't know how to do that using applescript, but I think I solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your script isn't escaped properly either. `spawn 'echo "a"'` would result in an error because of the double quotes.

You can use the run handler to pass arguments to osascript:

```
#!/bin/bash

osascript - "$*" <<END
on run args
tell app "Terminal"
do script item 1 of args
do script "logout" in window 1
end
end
END
```

`"$*"` is like `"$@"` but with all arguments in a single word.

Comment: This approach kills the original Terminal window the instant the new one is spawned.

Comment: @Fenhl What do you mean with kill? The logout command should be run in the opened window. If you actually want to close the new window, replace `do script "logout" in window 1` with `close window 1`.

Comment: I meant closes, sorry. And I don't know a lot about AppleScript, but it looks like `window 1` refers to the window where I called the `spawn` script.