# Linux shell scripting: How can I stop a first program when the second will have finished?

Tags: linux, shell, scripting

I have two programs in Linux (shell scripts, for example):

```
NeverEnding.sh
AllwaysEnds.sh
```

The **first one does never stop**, so I wanna run it in **background**.
The **second one does stop** with no problem.

I would like to make a **Linux shell script** that **calls them both**, but automatically stops (kill, for example) the first **when the second will have finished**.

Specific command-line tools allowed, if needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can send the first into the background with `&` and get the PID of it by `$!`. Then after the second finishes in the foreground you can kill the first:

```
#!/bin/bash

NeverEnding.sh &
pid=$!

AllwaysEnds.sh

kill $pid
```

You don't actually need to save the pid in a variable, since `$!` only gets updated when you start a background process, it's just make it more easy to read.

Comment: It works fine, @fejese, thanks you. Should it be possible to pass a parameter to `AllwaysEnds.sh`?

Comment: Sure, just add the parameter as you'd call it from the command line: `AllwaysEnds.sh --answer 42`

Comment: Sorry, @fejese, I was talking about adding parameters when calling the main scripts, the shell script that start both programs and close the first after finishing the second. `AllwaysEnd.sh` should receive this `--answer 42` parameter.

Comment: @SopalajodeArrierez You can change this script with `AllwaysEnds.sh "$@"`. It will pass all the arguments of the main script to `AllwaysEnds.sh`. For details see [this guide](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html). BTW, it also explains `$!` and contains a couple of examples on job control.

Comment: I almost second @Andrey's comment, except for the quotes around `$@`. But that depends on what you want to achieve. If you want all separate parameters passed as they are to `AllwaysEnds.sh` (btw it's always) then you don't need the quotes. You only need them if you want to pass all parameters that you gave to the wrapper script to `AllwaysEnds.sh` as the first and only parameter.

Comment: `$ ./test.sh --answer 42 : ($@  arg #1) --answer ($@ arg #2) 42 ("$@" arg #1) --answer ("$@" arg #2) 42`; `$ ./test.sh '--answer 42' : ($@  arg #1) --answer ($@ arg #2) 42 ("$@" arg #1) --answer 42 ("$@" arg #2)`

Comment: @fejese: [`"$@"` has special meaning inside double-quotes](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_05_02). It doesn't work as you think it does. See [Propagate all arguments in a bash shell script](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4824590/4279)

Comment: Thanks @J.F.Sebastian, that was useful and new.