# How to translate an alias into a real file?

Tags: shell, alias

Most of the time, an alias works well, but some times, the command is executed by other programs, and they find it in the PATH, in this situation an alias not works as well as a real file.

e.g.

I have the following alias:

```
alias ghc='stack exec -- ghc'
```

And I want to translate it into an executable file, so that the programs which depending on it will find it correctly.  And the file will works just like the alias does, including how it process it's arguments.

So, is there any tool or scripts can help doing this?

Comment: Where is the program `ghc` located? It must be in your search `path` otherwise you must provide that information in the `alias`.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I have no ghc in my path, but the alias `stack exec -- ghc` works just like ghc, that's why I'm uing this alias, but other programs which trying to find ghc failed, So I want to mock a `ghc` in my path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my solution, I created a file named `ghc` as following:

```
#!/bin/sh
stack exec -- ghc "$@"
```

The reason why there is double quote around `$@` is explained here: [Propagate all arguments in a bash shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4824590/propagate-all-arguments-in-a-bash-shell-script)

Answer (score 0):

> So, is there any tool or scripts can help doing this?

A *lazy* question for a simple problem...  Here's a function:

```
alias2script() { 
    if type "$1" | grep -q '^'"$1"' is aliased to ' ; then 
        alias | 
        { sed -n "s@.* ${1}='\(.*\)'\$@#\!/bin/sh\n\1 \"\${\@}\"@p" \
                 > "$1".sh
          chmod +x "$1".sh
          echo "Alias '$1' hereby scriptified.  To run type: './$1.sh'" ;}
    fi; }
```

Let's try it on the common `bash` *alias* `ll`:

```
alias2script ll
```

Output:

```
Alias 'll' hereby scriptified.  To run type: './ll.sh'
```

What's inside `ll.sh`:

```
cat ll.sh
```

Output:

```
#!/bin/sh
ls -alF "${@}"
```