# Bash Wrapper Script That Takes Arguments Via Flags And Runs Another Script With Those Flags

Tags: bash

I know that there are variations of this concept, but I haven't found a case where there is a script that takes in a bunch of arguments via flags that is called by another script.  How can I avoid duplicate arguments that need to be maintained?  Example:

`script-to-be-called.sh` takes in arguments like this:

```
function get_user_args() {
  while getopts ":a:b:c:" opt; do
    case ${opt} in
      h )
        usage
        ;;
      a )
        abc=$OPTARG
        ;;
      b )
        efg=$OPTARG-`uuidgen`
        ;;
      c )
        hi=$OPTARG
        ;;
...
      \? )
        echo "Invalid Option: -$OPTARG" 1>&2
        exit 1
        ;;
    esac
  done
  shift $((OPTIND -1))

}
```

Running it on its own looks like this:

```
./script-to-be-called -a xyz -b mno -c helloworld
```

So, now if I have a wrapper script that calls it, how can I avoid having an identical `get_user_args` function?  For example, how can `wrapper-script.sh` run as shown below where users can pass in arguments in the same way as above without duplicating the get_user_args function.

```
function generate_parallel_runs() {
  while read params
  do
    echo "./script-to-be-called -a $argA -b $argB -c $argC" >> parallel_commands_list.sh
  done < params.txt

  parallel < "parallel_commands_list.sh"

  #once the parallel runs are created, remove the file
  rm parallel_commands_list.sh
}
```

Ideally:

```
./wrapper-script.sh -a xyz -b mno -c helloworld
```

Comment: You have access to all arguments in the special `$@` array, you could use that in the wrapper script to pass them through, as in `./script-to-be-called "$@"`? Also, it looks like the inner script has `getopts` wired up incorrectly, all parameters that take arguments need a `:` after the letter, i.e., `:a:b:c:`.

Comment: Ohh I didn't realize you could access the arguments passed via flags in that manner.  So, I guess there's nothing unique about this question at all.  What you suggested works fine-- users can even pass in `-h` and see the help menu of the script being called

Comment: If an admin somehow reads this, feel free to close it unless someone comes up with a better design that I should be considering

Comment: Would you say [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4824590/3266847) is a good duplicate target?

Comment: Ya I think so.  I had even read that one before posting this.  I just thought there would be a nuance to taking in arguments with flags